# Extract filters from R Shiny Datatable

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard, dt

I have a [DT data table](https://rstudio.github.io/DT/) in R Shiny and I have enabled column filtering by setting `filter="top"` within `renderDT()`. I now want to extract the user-applied filters so I can save them in variables server-side and reapply them when -- for instance -- a database is updated, requiring an update of the table.

Here's a MWE using Shiny Dashboard:

```
library(shiny)           #  Shiny web app
library(shinydashboard)  #  Dashboard framework for Shiny
library(plotly)          #  Plotly interactive plots
library(DT)

ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(),
  dashboardSidebar(),
  dashboardBody(
    fluidRow(column(12, DTOutput("table")))
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  fileData <- reactiveFileReader(1000, session, 'test.csv', read.csv)
  output$table <- renderDT(fileData(), filter = "top")
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

To reiterate, I'd like to save the filters (for instance, a user might select a range of numeric values or a specific factor from one of the filter boxes) as `input$` variables so I can use them on the server side.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think the simplest way to do this is to just add

```
options = list(stateSave = TRUE)
```

inside the `renderDT()` function. Then, within the `server`, the state of the table can be accessed at any time with `input$<tableID>_state` (my table is just called "table" so this becomes `input$table_state`:

```
observeEvent(input$table_state, {
  str(input$table_state)
})
```

#### The whole solution is then:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(plotly)
library(DT)

ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(),
  dashboardSidebar(),
  dashboardBody(
    box(DTOutput("table"))
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  fileData <- reactiveFileReader(1000, session, 'www/test.csv', read.csv)
  output$table <- renderDT(fileData(), filter = "top",
    options = list(stateSave = TRUE))

  observeEvent(input$table_state, {
    str(input$table_state)
  })

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

#### Sample output within the RStudio console:

```
List of 6
 $ time   : num 1.54e+12
 $ start  : int 0
 $ length : int 10
 $ order  : list()
 $ search :List of 4
  ..$ search         : chr ""
  ..$ smart          : logi TRUE
  ..$ regex          : logi FALSE
  ..$ caseInsensitive: logi TRUE
 $ columns:List of 5
  ..$ :List of 2
  .. ..$ visible: logi TRUE
  .. ..$ search :List of 4
  .. .. ..$ search         : chr ""
  .. .. ..$ smart          : logi TRUE
  .. .. ..$ regex          : logi FALSE
  .. .. ..$ caseInsensitive: logi TRUE
  ..$ :List of 2
  .. ..$ visible: logi TRUE
  .. ..$ search :List of 4
  .. .. ..$ search         : chr "[\"0\"]"
  .. .. ..$ smart          : logi TRUE
  .. .. ..$ regex          : logi FALSE
  .. .. ..$ caseInsensitive: logi TRUE
  ..$ :List of 2
  .. ..$ visible: logi TRUE
  .. ..$ search :List of 4
  .. .. ..$ search         : chr "[\"8\"]"
  .. .. ..$ smart          : logi TRUE
  .. .. ..$ regex          : logi FALSE
  .. .. ..$ caseInsensitive: logi TRUE
  ..$ :List of 2
  .. ..$ visible: logi TRUE
  .. ..$ search :List of 4
  .. .. ..$ search         : chr ""
  .. .. ..$ smart          : logi TRUE
  .. .. ..$ regex          : logi FALSE
  .. .. ..$ caseInsensitive: logi TRUE
  ..$ :List of 2
  .. ..$ visible: logi TRUE
  .. ..$ search :List of 4
  .. .. ..$ search         : chr ""
  .. .. ..$ smart          : logi TRUE
  .. .. ..$ regex          : logi FALSE
  .. .. ..$ caseInsensitive: logi TRUE
```

Note the `search` lists which show the filters applied to each column.

#### Bonus

For super-easy filter extraction, use [`input$table_search_columns`](https://rstudio.github.io/DT/shiny). This gives the same result as using `sapply`:

```
sapply(input$table_state$columns, function(x) x$search$search)
```

This will give something like

```
[1] ""        "[\"0\"]" "[\"8\"]" ""        ""
```

for the above example.

Comment: Better than my answer!

Comment: Thanks for pointing to `input$table_serach_columns`. Very useful! Any idea how to parse the output (removing brackets and quotes), especially when multiple features are selected per column e.g `"[\"AAK1\",\"AARS\"]"`. Desired output would be `AAK1` and `AARS`

Comment: @cholland, I just used some regular expressions

Comment: @awwsmm can you give an example of a reactive table that updates to reflect the filtered state (i.e. how to apply `input$table_state` to `input$table`)

Comment: Also to contribute with the bonus answer, you can provide a clear string result ( instead of a array of empty and no empty values) by using he following lines:  `allVals <- sapply(input$table_state$columns, function(x) x$search$search)` and 
    `currentFilter <- paste0(allVals[!is.na(allVals) & allVals !=""],sep=";")
`

Comment: This doesn't seem to work when the columns are factors.  The returned state is empty.

Answer (score 1):

There may be a simpler way to do this, but here's my quick 5 minute solution:

Every time the table redraws (which will happen when you update a filter, but will also happen when you sort, paginate, or do anything else that causes a redraw), inject some javascript that looks for the value of the filter you're interested in. We can use then use [this method](https://deanattali.com/blog/advanced-shiny-tips/#message-javascript-r) to send the value as an input to the server side of the shiny app in R.

I will be using the `mtcars` dataset rather than a csv file, I'm using a slightly simpler template than what you provided, and I'll be specifically looking for filtered values of the third column which is `disp`. This should be enough to help you solve your specific case.

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  "disp filter:",
  textOutput("dispOut"),
  DT::dataTableOutput("table")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$table <- DT::renderDataTable(
    DT::datatable(
      mtcars,
      filter = "top",
      options = list(
        drawCallback = JS('function(){ Shiny.onInputChange("dispFilter", this.api().table().columns(3).search()[0]); }')
      )
    )
  )

  output$dispOut <- renderText(input$dispFilter)
}

shinyApp(ui,server)
```

**Edit:** the other answer by @awwsmm is better, this one is more javascript based, the other is more shiny