# Return DT filters when columns are factors

Tags: r, shiny, dt

I referenced [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52858889/extract-filters-from-r-shiny-datatable) to return the currently set filters on a DT datatable in R Shiny.

The problem I have is that if the columns are set to factors, the returned state is empty.

[image]

How do use factors as columns, but still learn the state of the user-filters?

```
library(shiny)
library(data.table)
library(dplyr)
library(DT)

# Define UI for application that draws a histogram
ui <- fluidPage(
  
  # Application title
  titlePanel("DT"),
  
  # Sidebar with a slider input for number of bins
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      
    ),
    
    # Show a plot of the generated distribution
    mainPanel(
      DT::dataTableOutput("demoTable")
    )
  )
)

# Define server logic required to draw a histogram
server <- function(input, output) {
  data <- MASS::Cars93[, c("Manufacturer", "Model", "Type", "Price")]
  
  observeEvent(input$demoTable_state, {
    str(input$demoTable_state)
  })
  
  output$demoTable <- DT::renderDataTable({
    DT::datatable( data 
                   ,extension = 'Buttons' ,
                   filter = list(position = 'top', clear = FALSE),
                   options = list(
                     paging = TRUE,
                     searching = TRUE,
                     fixedColumns = TRUE,
                     autoWidth = TRUE,
                     ordering = TRUE,
                     dom = 'lftsp' ,
                     stateSave = TRUE ,
                     order = list(list(1,'asc'),list(2,'asc'))
                     #buttons = c('copy', 'csv', 'excel'),  
                     # modify this for full download. github.com/rstudio/DT/issues/267
                   ),
                   escape = FALSE,
                   class='display',
                   rownames = FALSE
    )
  }, server=FALSE, escape=FALSE)
}

# Run the application
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: This works with `server=TRUE`.

Comment: In my actual problem, when I set `server=TRUE`, I don't get any data displayed at all.  When I set `server=FALSE`, I get all of my data as expected.  So I'm not sure that's a solution for me.